# Convert a string within a list to an element in the list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am using python data to create a ReportLab report.  I have a list that looks like this:

```
mylist = [['a b c   d   e   f'],['g h i   j   k   l']]
```

and want to convert it to look like this:

```
mylist2 = [[a,b,c,d,e],[g,h,i,j,k,l]]
```

the first list gives me a "List out of index" error when building the report.

the second list works in ReportLab, but columns and formatting in this list aren't what I want.

What is the best method to convert mylist 1 to mylist2 in python?

Comment: Do you mean `mylist2 = [["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], ["g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"]]`? The way you write it the characters have to be variable names and that makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

string to list can be done using split() method.

try `mylist[1][0].split()` and `mylist[0][0].split()`

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = [['a b c   d   e   f'],['g h i   j   k   l']]
import re
space_re = re.compile(r'\s+')
output = []
for l in mylist:
    element = l[0]
    le = re.split(space_re, element)
    output.append(le)
```

This not best answer but it will work fine.!

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing idea from Jibin Mathews, I tried the following

```
new_list = [mylist[0][0].split(), mylist[1][0].split()]
```

and it prints

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']]
```

I saw 'f' is missing in your final list. Is that the mistake?